# Can we execute multiple commands in the same command prompt launched by python

Tags: python

There is an excel file which contains the paths of multiple scenarios. I am using `os.system(command)` in a for loop. In each iteration, a path is read from excel file and executes the scenario for that path.

My problem is that every time, by using `os.system()`, a CMD opens, execute one command and close. In next iteration, again second path is read and execute it and CMD close. Here CMD pop-ups again and again. And the system is busy during that period and not able to do other task. I want to execute all the commands(scenario) in one CMD because I would like to minimize it and use the system for other task.

In each iteration, there are two main steps:

1. `os.chdir(PATH)`
2. `os.system(path of exe+" "+name of config file that is present at PATH")`

Can it be done by using subprocess. If yes please give me some example how it can be implemented?

Comment: Could you post the code you've used to run the contents of the Excel file?

Comment: What do you mean by "the system"? The Python interpreter? That should block during `os.system`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module, try something like this :

```
from subprocess import call
import os.path

def call_scenario(path, config_file):
    retcode = call(["path/of/exe", os.path.join(path,config_file)])
    if retcode != 0:
       print "Something bad happened : %s"%retcode
```

When using [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), the `shell=False` parameter will avoid to launch a cmd to do something.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done - here is a quick example using multiprocessing (Python 2.6 or newer )

The example bellow uses a Unix command ("ls") and unixes paths ("/usr, etc...) but just replace those with your needed commands and paths.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

paths = ["/tmp", "/usr", "/usr/include"]


def exec_(path):
    p = Process()
    p.run = lambda: os.system("ls %s" % path)
    p.start()

for path in paths:
    exec_(path)
```

Another option, if you need some sophisticated control on what is running, return codes, etc... is to make use of the Fabric project -
Although it is aimed at executingmultiple commands on different hosts using ssh - I think it culd be used for different paths on the same host.

URL for fabric:
http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.3/index.html

Comment: you're speaking of subprocess while using multiprocessing in your example, and I'm not sure that `ls -l` will work on the OP computer as he's talking about exe, Excel and CMD that sounds like a windows...

Comment: Unfortunately @CédricJulien is right - at least when it comes to the "Windows" part.

Comment: "multiprocessing", sorry (fixed) - as for the posix example, this is an example code - it will work if one replace the parameters and the external command for whatever

Answer (score 0):

To run `c:\path\to\exe` for all `config.ini` from each `path` *simultaneously* and to change current directory to `cwd` before it is executed:

```
from subprocess import Popen

processes = [Popen([r"c:\path\to\exe", "config.ini"], cwd=path) for path in paths]
for p in processes: p.wait()
```

If you don't want to run all commands in parallel then use `subprocess.call()` with the same arguments as for `subprocess.Popen()`.